# Fetching from Database: Property or Method?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a class that I'd like to let it get a record from a database. I need to make sure that there's at most one record. The record should be a single match to the class, based on the OrderId.

I feel like a property getter would make more sense than a method, but I know that property getters should [avoid throwing Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) and `.Single()/.SingleOrDefault()` could end up throwing one. I feel like the method might make people think that it was fetching from the database each time. Either way, I'd have the result cached in a local field.

What is the best practice for something like this? I have an example of what my code is like below.

N.B.: I know that ideally we'd have a unique index on the DB column to make sure it's unique, it's not possible to do with the vendor database we're using.

```
class OrderDetails
{
    DbOrder _order;
    string OrderId { get; set; }

    DbOrder Order // property way
    {
        get{
            if (this._order == null)
                this._order = dbContext.Where(x => x.OrderId == this.OrderId).SingleOrDefault();
            return _order;
        }
    }

    DbOrder GetOrder() // method way
    {
        if (this._order == null)
            this._order = dbContext.Where(x => x.OrderId == this.OrderId).SingleOrDefault();
        return _order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say a property should always raise an exception if it's needed, same as anywhere (just as similarly as it should be avoided if possible).

More to the point, I think it's that properties shouldn't have "side effects", and although yours does not strictly, this is the closest thing I can liken it to. It seems like "a lot to do" (open db connection, queried data, piped results) for a property when a method could be more descriptive: you kind of expect a method will do more legwork ad hoc

Comment: The database connection may or may not already be open, that's outside the scope of this class.

Comment: I stand by what I said

Comment: I understand that. Part of the problem is that others will know that this record comes from a database, and I don't want them to think that it's being fetched each time the method is called. Hell, even just looking at the method name makes me wonder, and I'm the one that wrote it.

Comment: I would say that the sole point of properties as opposed to using fields is that they can execute side effects, and the caller shouldn't have to worry too much about whether they do or not.  There isn't a right answer here, it's really about how you want consumers to perceive the class.  If the fact that sometimes this member will need to hit the DB is very important, I would make it a method, but if you want to isolate the consumer from the underlying DB implementation a property is okay.  Existing conventions in the same codebase are a big factor here to.  It's about consumer expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to think by yourself what your class `OrderDetails` represents:

- It represents the details of an order.
- or: it represents some access to some storage where order details can be fetched (and possibly changed).

If `OrderDetails` would represent the first, then it would simply be some POCO with only get and set properties.

Clearly, your `OrderDetails` represent the 2nd. Your class is meant to ease the access to the storage of the order details. It also hides the storage, so if the storage changes (database changes structure, or not a database anymore but in-memory data), users of your class won't have to change.

The function of your `OrderDetails` is also more an `access to order details`, because two objects of class `OrderDetails` would not mean two order details, but two methods to access the same order details.

If you didn't mean this, but you wanted every order detail object to represent its own order details, consider changing the class such that it contains the fetched data of the order details, not some access to fetch the data. Also make some functions that fetches the data and returns an object with the fetched data.

Consider making static functions like `OrderDetails.Create(...)` or even better, create an `order detail factory class` that creates `OrderDetail` objects for you filled with the desired data.

If you have separated the data from the methods to fetch the data your question will be answered: the methods to fetch the data will be raising exceptions if fetching the data does not succeed. The POCO object that contains the fetched data won't have to raise exceptions: the data itself is not wrong

If you really meant, that your `OrderDetail` is not the detail of the order, but some access to get the order details, then getting the details of the order is clearly not a property of the access object, but some functionality of this access object.

Another reason to separate the order details from the access to the storage of the order details would be consistency if data. if your Order Detail has some related properties, and you would get them from the storage in separate calls, how would you guarantee that your related data does not change between the first and the second call?

For instance: Get Postcode and City of the address of a person in separate calls. If the data of the person you are querying is changing between your first and second call, because the person is moving, then you could get the old Postcode and the new City

Summarized: make sure that it is clear to you what parts of your design represents the data itself, or some access to get the data, and design your classes accordingly. Data classes will be filled with property get/set, Access classes will be filled with Functions that return the data classes